# cyclic dependency on custom modules does not work

Tags: node.js, npm

I have setup 2 custom npm modules let say the scope name is "company". My modules a and b have the following structure:

---

### module @company/a :

```
f1(x){moduleB.f2(x);}

f2(x){...}

module.exports = {f1, f2};

// cyclic dependency require

var moduleB = require('@company/b');
```

---

### module @company/b :

```
f1(x){...}

f2(x){moduleA.f2(x);}

module.exports = {f1, f2};

// cyclic dependency require

var moduleA = require('@company/a');
```

When I now require module @company/a and fire f1(x), I get the following error :

> TypeError: moduleB.f2 is not a function

I have correctly required the cyclic dependent modules after the export and I still get an empty object for the moduleB ...

Does anyone know what the problem is ?

Comment: Using local file a.js, b.js and c.js this works fine. What does your respective package.json look like for each package?

Comment: In `@company/a` do a `console.log(moduleB)`

Comment: console.log(moduleB) gives me an empty object like I said

Comment: the respective package.json files include the correct respective modules with th ecorrect versions

Comment: I asked what the package.json looked like. I assume this is private information and you don't want to share them. That's fine though. What does `console.log(moduleA)` look like from B?

Comment: console.log(moduleA) from b shows me all of the correct module functions. So b does correctly require a

Comment: Cool. Since they both export the same way using `module.exports` my bet there's something odd in package.json for B. Is `main` set correctly?

Comment: the package.json seems to be fine on both modules. main is pointing correctly to index.js. The Modules did actually work correctly before and have a lot of more functions and require more company modules, but just after I have updated the module to use cyclic dependent functions of a and b, this error did occur

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167180/discussion-between-ralphtheninja-and-sami-analyst).

Comment: Now I have maybe found a potential source of the problem. Actually the module b (which comes as an empty object when it gets required by a) does have a submodule, Lets call it module c. this submodule does require module a just normaly (not after module.exports). So could there be a problem by this submodules dependency ? a -> b -> c ( -> a  before module exports) . Does this result to b not beeing initialized correctly (empty) when fired by a ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by looking into the dependencies of the submodules like In my comment before  **a** -> **b** -> **c** -> **a** ( last is required  before module exports). So I just moved all of my company scoped modules after module.exports. Which does raise another question. Is there any disadvantage or anything to consider when moving all module initializations after module.exports ?

Comment: Not really. I'm more wondering why you need this circular dependency in the first place. Maybe a and b should just be the same object. When things turn tricky like this, it's usually a design flaw somewhere.

Comment: Actually no, the modules a and b are much bigger and complex than demonstrated in the example. You need more details to just give a Statement like that.

Comment: Fair enough! You could also pass objects to each other so you don't need the requires.

Comment: My Problem ist solved correctly for the given context I described. I think the solution of passing objects instead of requiring modules would take the need of modules as a whole, but there are enough reasons why nodejs and npm build this modular system. In my case it makes a lot of sense to use modules, whereby this discussion does not add any important Infos to the question. There are a Lot of ways to Solve this Problem, but there are Just some soltions which are reasonable